# How to check if a part of a string is in a list of elements?

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm trying to check the text element in a df column, to see if any part of that text is in a list of element

I tried this, but it seems I can't pass a list in the function

```
name=['park','school','hospital']

df['trip_pattern_txt'].str.contains(name)
```

> unhashable type: 'list'